# Ruby Regex - get persons name

Tags: ruby, regex

Given consistent strings like this:

```
Manual  stage: <b>Release</b> by <a href="https://test/builds/browse/user/a0123456">Joe Bloggs</a>


Changes by <a href="https://test/builds/browse/user/b234556">John Doe</a>
```

is there a simple regex I could use to pull the persons name?
is there a simple regex I could to pull the ID (which is at the end of the URL e.g. b1234345)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it’s better to use [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/), here is a simple regex:

```
▶ /(?<=\D)(\d+)\">([^<]+)<\/a>/ =~ \
  '<a href="https://test/builds/browse/user/b234556">John Doe</a>'
#⇒ 42
▶ $~
#⇒                                        ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓     ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
#⇒ #<MatchData "234556\">John Doe</a>" 1:"234556" 2:"John Doe">
```

To get the number and person, use:

```
num, person = /(?<=\D)(\d+)\">([^<]+)<\/a>/.
  match('<a href="https://test/builds/browse/user/b234556">John Doe</a>').
  captures
#⇒ ["234556", "John Doe"]
```

Comment: lol can you split it out in to two separate regex?

Comment: Unless I have understood why would one split it into two separate regexps, I won’t. Please see an update.

Comment: thanks for the help, its working but its missing the first letter of the id:  e.g a123456 or b223454 is coming in as 123456 or 223454